# How to print the position of a gameObject in a list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list and text:

```
List<GameObject> EnteredPlayers = new List<GameObject>();
public Text finishText;
```

When the player enters the trigger, they will be added to the list:

```
if (col.gameObject.tag == "finish") {

        EnteredPlayers.Add(player);
        finishText.text = //player's position in list here
    }
```

I would like to print the player's position in the list. For example, if their position is [0] then the text would say `1st place`.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: A) Get the count of the objects in the list before you add your object, that's the position. B) Use [`List<T>.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
// Add the player
EnteredPlayers.Add(player);

// Get the position
int position = EnteredPlayer.Count

// Create a dictionary with the position names
// Put this dictionary outside of your method managing the games
Dictionary<string, string> positionNames = new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    { "1", "First" },
    { "2", "Second" },
    { "3", "Third" }
};

// Assign the label text
finishText.Text = positionNames[position.ToString()];
```